# Return the multiply of a column

Tags: r, dataframe

In the below, the data frame index denotes the value while t1:t2 denotes the number of times that specific value was recorded at a specific point in time. For example index 10 at t1 equals 1 suggesting that it was made 1 records; at t2 there are 4 records, whole at t3 and t4 just 1. I would like to return the values from  columns t1:t4 based on an index column

Input:

```
index t1 t2 t3 t4
   10  1  4  1  1
   20  2  5  1  0
   30  3  6  1  0
   40  0  0  0  2 

Output:

       t1 t2  t3 t4
       10 10  10 10
       20 10  20 40
       20 10  30 40
       30 10  NA NA
       30 20  NA NA
       30 20  NA NA
       NA 20  NA NA
       NA 20  NA NA
       NA 30  NA NA  
       NA 30  NA NA
       NA 30  NA NA
       NA 30  NA NA
       NA 30  NA NA
       NA 30  NA NA
```

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(index=c (10,20,30,40), 
                   t1 = c(1, 2, 3, 0), 
                   t2 = c(4, 5, 6, 0), 
                   t3 = c(1, 1,1,  0),
                   t4 = c(1, 0, 0, 2)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
                                                            
df
```

Comment: Do you want the output in one dataframe? I think this is not possible (or you have to fill up with `NA`s), as all columns in a data.frame need to have the same length/number of rows

Comment: @starja thanks yes i would like to ha NAs on the empty slots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `purrr` solution could be:

```
map(.x = names(df)[-1],
    ~ df %>%
     uncount(get(.x)) %>%
     select(!!.x := index) %>%
     rowid_to_column()) %>%
 reduce(full_join)

   rowid t1 t2 t3 t4
1      1 10 10 10 10
2      2 20 10 20 40
3      3 20 10 30 40
4      4 30 10 NA NA
5      5 30 20 NA NA
6      6 30 20 NA NA
7      7 NA 20 NA NA
8      8 NA 20 NA NA
9      9 NA 20 NA NA
10    10 NA 30 NA NA
11    11 NA 30 NA NA
12    12 NA 30 NA NA
13    13 NA 30 NA NA
14    14 NA 30 NA NA
15    15 NA 30 NA NA
```

Answer (score 5):

Base R and one line of code.

```r
Map(function(x) rep(df$index, x), df[,-1])
```

After update:

```r
maxy <- max(apply(df[,-1], 2, sum))
data.frame(Map(function(x) c(rep(df$index, x), rep(NA, maxy - sum(x))), df[,-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) rep(df$index, x))
data.frame(lapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))))
```

-output

```
#   t1 t2 t3 t4
#1  10 10 10 10
#2  20 10 20 40
#3  20 10 30 40
#4  30 10 NA NA
#5  30 20 NA NA
#6  30 20 NA NA
#7  NA 20 NA NA
#8  NA 20 NA NA
#9  NA 20 NA NA
#10 NA 30 NA NA
#11 NA 30 NA NA
#12 NA 30 NA NA
#13 NA 30 NA NA
#14 NA 30 NA NA
#15 NA 30 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option

```
list2DF(
  lapply(
    df[-1],
    function(x) `length<-`(rep(df$index, x), max(colSums(df[-1])))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   t1 t2 t3 t4
1  10 10 10 10
2  20 10 20 40
3  20 10 30 40
4  30 10 NA NA
5  30 20 NA NA
6  30 20 NA NA
7  NA 20 NA NA
8  NA 20 NA NA
9  NA 20 NA NA
10 NA 30 NA NA
11 NA 30 NA NA
12 NA 30 NA NA
13 NA 30 NA NA
14 NA 30 NA NA
15 NA 30 NA NA
```